# Python For loop to update a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to re-create a VBA macro that I have using Python. Could someone please tell me the FOR statement I should use, in order to get below result? Thank you very much.

file 1:

```
Product Colour  Price
Book    NaN 5
Table   NaN 10
Chair   NaN 7
```

file 2:

```
Colour 
Blue 
Red 
Green
```

Expected result (file 1) after the loop:

```
Product Colour Price    
Book    Blue    5
Table   Blue    10
Chair   Blue    7
Book    Red 5
Table   Red 10
Chair   Red 7
Book    Green   5
Table   Green   10
Chair   Green   7
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Images do not help!.

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope you can see the example now.

Comment: Yes, I am using Pandas.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But, I am getting some errors when trying to use the code you suggested:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First duplicate values of `df1` by length of `df2` and then use `list comprehesion` and [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) for `Colour` as:

```
from itertools import chain


df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': df1['Product'].values.tolist()*len(df2),
                   'Price'  : df1['Price'].values.tolist()*len(df2),
                   'Colour' : list(chain.from_iterable([[v]*len(df1) for v in df2['Colour'].values.tolist()]))})

print(df)
  Product  Price Colour
0    Book      5   Blue
1   Table     10   Blue
2   Chair      7   Blue
3    Book      5    Red
4   Table     10    Red
5   Chair      7    Red
6    Book      5  Green
7   Table     10  Green
8   Chair      7  Green
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Sandeep!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension, analogous to a nested `for` loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[product, colour, price] for colour in df2['Colour'] \
                   for product, price in zip(df1['Product'], df1['Price'])],
                  columns=['Product', 'Colour', 'Price'])

print(df)

  Product Colour  Price
0    Book   Blue      5
1   Table   Blue     10
2   Chair   Blue      7
3    Book    Red      5
4   Table    Red     10
5   Chair    Red      7
6    Book  Green      5
7   Table  Green     10
8   Chair  Green      7
```

Comment: When trying to read the data from a file, it does not work.
Could you pleaase help me to check ?

x = pd.read_excel('C:/Desktop/file1.xlsx')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=x)
df1

y = pd.read_excel('C:/Desktop/file2.xlsx') 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=y)
df2

df = pd.DataFrame([[Product, Colour, Price] for Colour in df2['Colour'] for Product, Price in zip(df1['Product'], df1['Price'])], columns=['Product', 'Colour', 'Price'])
df